# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in DBeaver

Tags: java, database, memory, memory-management, dbeaver

I have a `.sql` file with size `1047399KB`,I'm trying to run it on Windows10 with `4.00GB` RAM on DBeaver program, i got `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error

I tried many solutions but didn't work with me.
`file.sql -Xms128m -Xmx512m`, `file.sql -vmargs -Xmx1024M`, `file.sql -Xmx800m -Xms500m` all didn't work with me.

Comment: All depends on the underlining java application implementation. If it trys to load the whole file before process it, you have to allocate at least 2GB of memory

Comment: You may also have luck modifying the dbeaver.ini file to increase the heap size.

Comment: @ZeyadEtman : As per https://dbeaver.io/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1162. We can set max memory to 1GB. I tried with 2048 and 4096 but same issue faced. But when I tried with "-vmargs -Xmx1024m" it works well.

Comment: @Raedwald It's a question about DBeaver, not Java. This is not a duplicate.

Comment: @vintproxvintpro the accepted answer indicates it is a duplicate

Comment: @Raedwald not really. My answer just points to DBeaver's forum. "Duplicates" provided above don't relate to DBeaver other than by a long shot.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I encountered [same](https://dbeaver.io/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1162) [issue](https://dbeaver.io/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=596): every time you get it, you have to allocate more space and run DBeaver itself first with additional flags `-vmargs -Xmx*m`. Replace `*` with `2048` or `4096`.

It doesn't look like DBeaver takes garbage out when closing the script, so I had to restart application many times to check right amount of memory needed.

@Timothy Jannace just pointed out that you also can edit `dbeaver.ini`. [Example.](https://gist.github.com/souhaiebtar/9bc22ff3eafbba1542b5c05a70228a02)

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem! It's a bit worrying that a test of `SELECT * FROM LEFT JOIN` for a small database actually takes around 2GB ram.

Comment: @NicholasHumphrey Well, I noticed phpMyAdmin comes in handy for import task, for example, better than DBeaver and HeidiSQL. I was assuming that native software must provide more seamless experience and overtake memory limits of web application, but it's not the case with specific, database software, I guess.

Comment: I tried 1Crore data to important one DB to another DB but the tool is not responding. Then I have increased memory parameters in ".ini" file after that it's successfully imported. Hope it's helpful for someone.

Comment: can someone explain how to run DBeaver from command line? I am using Mac OS version. It seems it is an .app file

Comment: Try editing the values in the ini file instead. You should be able to find the file in the program directory of dbeaver. It should be called dbeaver.ini

Comment: @cryanbhu edit `dbeaver.ini` file as shown [here](https://gist.github.com/souhaiebtar/9bc22ff3eafbba1542b5c05a70228a02). Path should be something like `/Applications/DBeaverEE.app/Contents/Eclipse/dbeaver.ini`.

Comment: I changed two parameters on my dbeaver.ini file: -Xms500m
-Xmx4096m worked for me

Comment: 3 years later and this still works like a charm to prevent OOM exceptions.
The provided example link lists the typical paths, for non-standard in stalls the comment section on the gist is extremely helpful

Comment: @RivenSkaye yeah no shit, this one still blinks in my notifications every month xD

Comment: In Linux Mints its located here: /usr/share/dbeaver-ce